# ConstraintLayout внутри ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

Нужна помощь более опытных разработчиков. У меня возникла проблема с шаблоном для Fragment с прокруткой в android.
Нельзя прокрутить экран в самый конец в landscape формате экрана.
Не отображается часть информации расположенной в самом низу.
Кажется, что проблема в том, что фрагмент занимает места больше, чем может отобразиться на экране.
Не понимаю в каком месте ошибся. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Разметка fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainFragment">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/weather_icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_location" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/weatherIcon"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/temperature_view_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature_view_text"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/temp_temperature"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_description"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weather_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tableRow"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temperature_view_text" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_description">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/feels_like"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_scarf" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_feels_like"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/myWind"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_wind" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_wind_speed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </TableRow>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

разметка landscape layout для main activity, куда данный Fragment встраивается.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/frag_cont_view_second"
            android:name="ru.skillsnet.falchio.SecondFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/frag_cont_view_main"
            android:name="ru.skillsnet.falchio.MainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
    </TableRow>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">
```

Заменить на

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" //эта строка новая
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">
```

Это единственное, что приходит в голову

Comment: Спасибо, Вам! Проблема решилась.